# Power Query excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am trying to use a if formula in power query. For example, if the Column contains “guy” then value is male and the false value is “female”. I tried different ways and I can’t find the right formula to use in power query. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: if(A2="guy","Male","Female") at its most simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you are entering this into the `Add Custom Column` dialog, something like (for case-insensitive):

```
= if Text.Contains([Column],"guy", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then "male" else "female"
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are wanting to conditionally replace values in a column, based on the existing values in that column? If so, you can use the Table.ReplaceValue function in Power Query:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,
each [Gender],
each if [Gender] = "guy" then "male" else "female",
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Gender"})
```

That will change all values of "guy" to "male', and ALL other values to "female", as you stated.

You can also leave values in place that don't meet the criteria, by simply *referencing* the column name instead of a *specifying* a new value:

```
= Table.ReplaceValue(Source,
each [Gender],
each if [Gender] = "guy" then "male" else [Gender],
Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Gender"})
```

Create a table with a column called Gender, and load it to power query. Right-click on the column header and choose Replace Values to get the UI to build your statement for you, then replace the generated code with the above modification(s) and apply to your actual requirements. The key is using the **each** expression to tell Power Query to test at the row value level. If you omit **each**, you'll see the error:

*"Expression.Error: There is an unknown identifier. Did you use the [field] shorthand for a _[field] outside of an 'each' expression?"*

Answer (score 0):

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","ColumnName",each if[Column] ="""Guy""" then"""Male""" else"""Female""")
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the scenario. I have a column, called "Column", within which there are three records of "guys" and three records of girls.

[image]

Try this: click "fx" to add a new step and then type`= Table.AddColumn(#"your previous step name", "your new column name", each if Text.Contains([Column],"guy") then "male" else "female")`

Watch out M language is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Alex here, nice to meet you!

Firstly, ensure the data type of your column is set to text.

Now, make sure the column containing "guy" is consistently formatted throughout, as Power Query is case-sensitive. If you find discrepancies, head to the "Transform" tab, press "Format," and use the option to convert text to lowercase or capitalize the first letter.

Next, go to the "Add Column" tab, select "Conditional Column," and choose your column. For the condition, use "equals" and enter "guy." Then, set the value to "male" for true and "female" for the other results.

Good Luck! If you have more questions, feel free to ask.